# Fragment in FragmentStateAdapter become null when activity when switching between app

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have a bottomNavView with Viewpager2 using FragmentStateAdapter. I have 4 tabs. Before i was using viewpager. then, i switch to viewpager2 because of this error. But on viewpager2 same error is occurring.

When i switch between apps tiktok,facebook,instagram and come back to my app. its recreated. all 4 fragment are called from oncreateview() and so on. but my back button was not working. because onBackPress. I am accessing fragment. But the fragments are null. Althought, they are being recreated and displayed.

```
 if (binding.viewPager.currentItem == 3) {
       val frag = sectionsPagerAdapter.fragment3
}
```

after spending an entire day I was able to fix the problem by assigning it back to fragments but this doesn't seem like the best solution.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
   
        val activity = activity as ActivityMain
        activity.sectionsPagerAdapter.fragment2 = this
       
}
```

In Manifest

```
     <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityMain"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        
       />
```

This is my viewpager2 Adapter. before I was using lateinit val to fragments. still, i was getting error. At that time fragment was not null but it could not pass isadded. Another thing is that **createFragment doesn't get called** when activity is auto_recreated. but all fragment calls oncreateview

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter(  activity: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter( activity) {

val TAG = "SectionsPagerAdapter"

var fragment0: Fragment0? = null
var fragment3: Fragment1? = null
var fragment1: Fragment2? = null
var fragment2: Fragment3? = null



override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return 4

}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

     if (position == 0) {
        if(fragment0 == null){
            fragment0 = Fragment0()
        }

        return fragment0!!
    }
    if (position == 1) {
        if(fragment1 == null){
            fragment1 = Fragment1()
        }
        return fragment1!!

    }
    if (position == 2) {
        if(fragment2 == null){
            fragment2 = Fragment2()
        }
        return fragment2!!
    }
    if (position == 3) {
      if(fragment3 == null){
          fragment3 = Fragment3()
        }
        return fragment3!!
    }
    return Fragment0()

 }
```

}